# Partitioning with some condition in another column

Tags: sql

I have data like this:

```
some_data, p_column, type
pla, 1, a
bla, 1, b
sth, 1, a
sth, 2, a
```

Than lets say I partition by p_column over some descending dates in some_data and with rank I get:

```
some_data, p_column, type, rank
pla, 1, a, 1
bla, 1, b, 2
sth, 1, a, 3
sth, 2, a, 1
```

For each partition I want to select row with the lowest rank where the type is b, else if there is no row with type b in the partition I want to select row with the lowest rank with type a.

So I will get rows (for the example):

```
some_data, p_column, type, rank
bla, 1, b, 2
sth, 2, a, 1
```

If this is not clear, I attach pseudocode:

```
for each partition:
    if type b is in partition:
        select row b with lowest rank
    else:
        select row a with lowest rank
```

Comment: which `dbms` are you using?

Comment: I use pyspark, but this is a general question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One conceptual way of approaching this is to realize that you really want a double partition here, one layer for the `p_column` and a second layer for the `type`.  Based on your precedence rules, you want to give the `b` type a higher priority than `a`.  So we can partition on the `p_column` followed by the `type`, and then use row number again to choose the lowest record for each partition.

```
SELECT some_data, p_column, type
FROM
(
    SELECT some_data, p_column, type,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_column
                           ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'b' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT some_data, p_column, type,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p_column, type ORDER BY some_date_col) rank
        FROM yourTable
    ) t
    WHERE t.rank = 1
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY p_column;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: wouldn't we be using `ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc` or `ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'b' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`? otherwise it will pick record with type `a`

Comment: @zarruq No, if you reread the question you will see that the OP wants `b` first if available, then `a` if `b` be unavailable.  At least my query works for the sample data provided.

Comment: Yes, but in your current query, `b=1` will be sorted below `a=0` in default 
`asc` order.  I checked your demo and it is picking both records with type `a`.

Comment: @zarruq Apologies...that demo link was from an earlier edit.  I never updated to be in sync with this answer.

Comment: Welcome... +1 :-)